# How to access function in typescript?

Tags: angular, function, typescript, ionic2

I'm developing hybrid app using typescript and I wonder how to access a function in typescript.

This is my source code:

```
export class SuccessPage {
 public removeRoom(){
    console.log("removeroom");
 }
}
function getRoom(){
  var searchList = '';
  ....
  searchList += '   <li id=\'' + result.Item[0].room_num + '\'>';
  searchList += result.Item[i].dest_x + ', ' + result.Item[0].dest_y + 
               '<br><button class="removeRoom" onclick="removeRoom()"> </button></li>';
  ....
 }
```

I intend to access the `removeRoom` function. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a correct architecture (more on this later), but to answer your question, you could do one of 2 things:

1. Keep the `removeRoom` method as it is and to use it in other place you'd have to create an instance of `SuccessPage` class, i.e.:

   ```
   const page = new SuccessPage();
   page.removeRoom();
   ```
2. or make the `removeRoom` method `static` and use it without creating an instance:

   ```
   static removeRoom() {...} 

   /* ... *./

   SuccessPage.removeRoom()
   ```

   (Mind that `static` is only an option if the method doesn't work on instance fields (i.e. has no `this.something` or `this.doSomething()` inside.

Ok, so back to the "architecture" thing. If the `removeRoom` method does not have any references to the class instance and you do need to access it from other places, maybe it would be better to define it separately - as just an autonomic helper function (which you can just use directly from both the component and js code) or as a part of an Angular service (and in that case you'd, again, have to create an instance of the service to use it in js code outside Angular component)

Answer (score 0):

If you import the class into another file you can use the function by doing

```
import SuccessPage from './SuccessPage';

const page = new SuccessPage()
page.removeRoom()
```